# Inequalities for the sum of all digits

Tags: number-theory

Let $S(n)$ denotes the sum of all digits of the positive integer $n$

a) Prove, that $S(n) \le 5 \cdot S(2n)$ for every $n$.

b) Prove, that there exist infinitely many $n$, with $S(n)>1996 \cdot S(3n)$

*Author: V. Yasinski*

Comment: Equality in a is achieved at $\sum5\times10^i$. In b, consider the numbers $3333\dots3334$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put some work into the problem.

Comment: for those who closed down the question: I don't understand what the problem is. Okay the OP did not show any work of his own but if that is a problem you can just downvote. This is a clear, well posed question; would 2 lines explaining why the op has trouble really change all that much?